# QML DoubleValidator changing decimal to int on focus change

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using QML and I need textfields that only accept doubles. I used DoubleValidator for this. However, when I enter, for example a 0.2 in the textfield and hit tab, it will change the value to 2. The same holds for any number formatted as "0.00...0x". When I write any other number after the x, though, it will work correctly. I have no idea why this is and why anyone would want this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ניר The answer by GrecKo offers a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraphrasing my answer from forum.qt.io:

The DoubleValidator's behavior depends on the locale being used.
In some country like France for example, the period (.) is not a decimal marker but just a separator for thousands, millons, etc. The actual decimal marker is the comma (,).

If you want to force your DoubleValidator to use the english locale you can do so for each instance: `DoubleValidator { locale: "en"; /* ... */ }` or do it for the whole application once by calling [`QLocale::setDefault`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlocale.html#setDefault) before instantiating your `QGuiApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

I try this Example and it works well for me :

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Example")
    Rectangle{
        id:rect1
        y: 140
        height: 40
        border.width: 2
        anchors.rightMargin: 250
        anchors.leftMargin: 131
        antialiasing: true
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        TextInput {
            id: textInput
            anchors.fill: rect1
            font.pixelSize: 18
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            activeFocusOnTab: true
            focus: true
            validator: DoubleValidator{}


        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id:rect2
        y: 200
        height: 40
        border.width: 2
        anchors.rightMargin: 250
        anchors.leftMargin: 131
        antialiasing: true
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        TextInput {
            id: textInput2
            anchors.fill: rect2
            font.pixelSize: 18
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            activeFocusOnTab: true
            focus: true
            validator: DoubleValidator{}


        }
    }


    Text {
        id: text1
        x: 51
        y: 147
        width: 74
        height: 27
        text: qsTr("Text Input 1")
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    Text {
        id: text2
        x: 45
        y: 215
        width: 74
        height: 25
        text: qsTr("Text Input 2")
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
}
```

**output:**

[image]